# How to display keyboard with only numbers?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I want to display keyboard with only numbers, not Operators or any other symbols in keyboard.
I tried filter output already using inputFormatters in textfield.

Answer (score 1):

Here keyboardType is number so it will accept only number,
inputFormatters will format your input what you are typing.

```
TextField(  
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,  
   inputFormatters:<TextInputFormatter>. 
   [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]  
   decoration:InputDecoration(labelText: 'Number')
),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach? How does it compare to the existing approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add **inputFormatters** & **keyboardType** properties to enable keyboard with number inputs only to your TextField widget.

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

Answer (score 0):

if its in a TextField use this :

```
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
```

or you can use this :

```
 keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
```

also you can check this package

check this package [numeric_keyboard](https://pub.dev/packages/numeric_keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyboardType` property of `TextField`

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code.

```
 TextFormField(
           keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                            signed: true, decimal: true),
 inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                                       )
```

Comment: Please, provide info about why this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer